# json , получение с файла данных по ключу, запись в словарь

Tags: python, json, кодировка

json в файл записал данный с сайта.
Вот часть данных:

```
\"title\":\"Холодильник Side by Side\",\"isInComparison\":false,\"comparable\":true,\"productsInComparisonSize\":0,\"headers\":[\"iQ500\",\"Холодильник Side by Side\",\"\",\"177 x 91 cm\",\"Inox-easyclean\",\"KA90IVI
```

с помощью скрипта

```
f = open('json_data.txt','w', encoding='utf-8') # открывает файл для записи
json.dump(str(items), f, ensure_ascii=False) # ensure_ascii=False что бы русские символы отображались как есть
f.close()
```

Вопрос: как записать в словарь все значения ключа, которые  стоят после "title".

Пример : ключ - title , значение - Холодильник Side by Side.

```
[<form action="/fater/json/productlist?type=PRODUCT_LIST" class="js-ajax-request" data-ajax='{"url":"/fater/json/productlist?type=PRODUCT_LIST" ,  "requestParamSeries": [{"name":"standardFilters","checkFor":"values"},{"name":"rangeFilters","checkFor":"minValue","checkFor2":"maxValue"}], "dataRendering":true, "method":"POST"}' data-ajax-id="ajax-productlist" data-current-state-ajax-uri="/fater/json/productlist?categoryString=outletproducts&amp;type=PRODUCT_LIST" id="command" method="post" onsubmit="return false;"><script data-init-data="ajax-productlist" data-no-initial-callup="true" type="application/json">
                    {"response":{"cheap":"0","expensive":"0","items":[{"productIndex":"0","sku":"KA90IVI20R","type":"shop","title":"Холодильник Side by Side","isInComparison":false,"comparable":true,"productsInComparisonSize":0,"headers":["iQ500","Холодильник Side by Side","","177 x 91 cm","Inox-easyclean","KA90IVI20R"],"price":{"value":164990.0,"displayValue":"164 990,00 ₽"},"stockStatus":{"trafficLight":"green","text":"[G11]","buyable":true,"permanentlyNotAvailable":false},"link":"/fater/outlet/KA90IVI20R?breadcrumb=","productImage":{"src":"//media3.123.com/Product_Shots/{width}x{height}/MCSA00762608_E6797_KA90IVI20G_407519_def.jpg","alt":"KA90IVI20R"},"hookline":"Холодильник coolDuo серии iQ 500 типа \"side-by-side\" с технологией NoFrost, дополнительно оснащен дозатором для воды и льда.","keyBenefits":["Многопоточная система охлаждения multiAirflow обеспечивает равномерное распределение воздуха и охлаждение на всех уровнях холодильника.","Технология noFrost защищает от образования инея и избавит вас от необходимости размораживать холодильник.","Холодильник шириной 70см - существенное увеличение полезного объема для хранения продуктов.","Функция superFreezing понижает температуру на заданный промежуток времени, чтобы быстрее заморозить только что добавленные продукты.","Функция superCooling, или 'суперохлаждение', уменьшает температуру на заданное время,
```

Comment: Зачем `str(items)`?

Comment: Иначе в файл не записывается и выдается ошибка.

Comment: обреж строчку начиная от title и до первой запятой. потом выдерни все что между  этими символами " \"

Comment: так не сработает. "title" находится не в начале, и их много в файле, после которых надо текст в словарь записывать. Добавил код, что бы было более понятно

Comment: Учитесь поточнее формулировать.Так выходит что всё значения ключа записать,это ведь и есть стандартная операция Python-по ключу мы определяем все значение.Но в примере вроде понятно(правильно).Делай split() (метод строки) по запятой - split(',')->list->list[0]

Comment: `Иначе в файл не записывается и выдается ошибка` - нужно смотреть что за ошибка, а не действовать методом тыка. `str(items)` превращает словарь в строку, потом вы эту строку еще раз при записи в файл превращает в json, в итоге вы получаете лишний гемор при декодировании этих данных.